# JS - Timer Is Running Slow

Tags: javascript

I have written a simple JavaScript timer, but I've noticed that it runs at 1/3 speed. This timer is suppose to keep track how many MS has passed. I am unsure what I have done incorrectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/m3vYc/

```
time = 10000;
timer = setInterval( function() {
    time--;
    $('#timer').text(time);
}, 1);
```

Comment: The interval in *setInterval* is just a suggestion to the host environment to run code at a particular interval. The functions are queued and run when they can, not at exactly the instant you specify. The next will ony be queued when the previous one has run. Some browsers will only execute such code every 15ms or so. Expecting an accurate 1ms interval in any user agent is ambitious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in assuming that your computer can keep timers of 1 millisecond.

Some browsers will use the computer's clock, which in Windows ticks every 16ms (1/60th of a second, ie the framerate of your screen). Others will override this for a somewhat more accurate 3ms, which is why you are seeing a result of 1/3 speed.

Instead, use Delta Timing:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsed = now-start;
    var timeleft = 10000-elapsed; 
    $("#timer").text(timeleft);
},25);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m3vYc/1/)

Comment: That's an interesting solution - to base your timer off your system's current time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firing a function on each millisecond will clog your browser pretty fast. After all, jQuery is performing a DOM manipulation and it does take a real timelapse, even if tiny.

You should:

- fire it with a higher interval,
- instead of keeping track of a global time variable, use the browser current timestamp with `new Date().getTime()`
- Add the function to the stack to avoid itself from becoming an obstacle

something like:

```
var time=new Date().getTime()+10000;
timer = setInterval( function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var timediff=time-new Date().getTime();
        $('#timer').text(timediff);
    },0);
}, 100);
```

setting timeout to 0 will fire it inmediately unless there's something enqueued in the stack.

Comment: Why do you do `+10000`? Also, are you sure it should be `time - new Date().getTime()`, rather than `new Date().getTime() - time`?