# Stopwatch in Javascript is slower than normal time

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to make a stopwatch in JavaScript that could count milliseconds, seconds and minutes. This is what I have: (you can stop the timer by pressing space)

```js
var counter = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
var miliseconds = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;

function Add() {
  miliseconds++;
  if (miliseconds >= 99) {
    miliseconds = 0;
    seconds++;

    if (seconds >= 59) {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++;
    }
  }

  counter.textContent = (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" +
    (seconds ? (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds) : "00") + ":" +
    (miliseconds ? (miliseconds > 9 ? miliseconds : "0" + miliseconds) : "00");

  Timer();
}

function Timer() {
  t = setTimeout(Add, 10);
}

Timer();

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 32) {
  clearTimeout(t);
}

});
```

```html
<h1 id="counter">00:00:00</h1>
```

The problem is that it seems to not go at the proper speed, meaning that when I compare it to other timers, it gradually becomes slower than them (i.e the speed at which the timer is counting slows down over time).  So suddenly, there are 5-second differences, then it becomes 7-second differences and so on.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the answer to this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975537/js-timer-is-running-slow

Comment: The interval for setTimeout is a minimum, and you have to allow for the time for the function to run between calls, it's all cumulative.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you

Comment: Actually, I just re-checked, and I am sorry for jumping to conclusions so fast. I know where the problem is but I have no idea what to do to fix it, in the context of my timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a **startTime** variable, then calculate the **elapsedTime**, and use that to calculate additional variable to show.

```
var startTime = Date.now();
setTimeout(function(){
    var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    // Additional code to calculate hour, minute, second, milisecond here
}, 10);
```